# Slice Matrix matlab no loop

Tags: matlab

i have the following code, where `d` is a matrix with dimension 94x290:

```
samples=268;
dim_cov=23;
for q=1:samples
    D(:,q)=(sum(d(:,q+(1:dim_cov)-1),2));
end
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop?

Comment: A little off-topic, but `q + dim_cov` exceeds the number of rows in `d` (268 + 31 = 299).

Comment: hi sorry! for my mistake dim_cov it's 23

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
dim_cov = 23;
cs = [zeros(size(d,1), 1) cumsum(d, 2)];
result = cs(:,1+dim_cov:end) - cs(:,1:end-dim_cov);
```

Comment: hello I have different results, if I try your code, starting with the size of the array result, which must be of a size 94x268

Comment: ..sorry i have written dim_cov=31 but is dim_cov=23;